# Geometry Nodes and Exporting (Creating a mesh) in Blender 2.92

Tags: mesh, export, normals, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to export Geometry Nodes geometry to an FBX.

When I import the file elsewhere, though , there don't seem to be any normals associated with the Geometry Nodes object.  Typically, I'm able to import modified geometry using traditional modifiers just fine, but nothing doing with Geometry Nodes, despite them living inside the "Modifiers" tab.

Even trying to apply the modifications is problematic.  If geometry nodes are applied to a Point Cloud, then *Apply* just gets me a `Cannot Apply Modifier` error message.  If they're tied to a mesh, then *Apply* causes the generated geometry to disappear altogether.

I'm very new to Blender, so it may be that I'm just butting up against my own ignorance, but I have been searching for some kind of answer for hours with no luck. Many thanks in advance.

**Node Tree :**

[image]

[Download Blender File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/esj9b9oarc3oz7w/geo-nodes-apply-bug-demo.blend?dl=1)

Comment: Hi, please [edit] your question and share an image of the scene and geo node tree so that other users may see what you are working with...

Comment: Good call @Timaroberts - I've updated with the file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after filing a bug report with Blender, I got a partial answer from HQ.

> To get the instance geometry from the modifier, use the "Make Instances Real" operator. Applying modifiers on point clouds isn't supported yet.  For the other parts, we have this task: T85281.

This doesn't seem to directly address the export issue, but it's a start. For more info, head over to [Task T85281 : Support piping legacy modifiers with the geometry nodes modifiers](https://developer.blender.org/T85281).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this thing is related to your problem, but i just discovered a way to export grass as FBX which I was spreading using geometry nodes(point instance node, to be precise).

So I used "make instances real" on the object that had the geometry nodes modifier and it made all the grass planes as separate objects in my hierarchy, and then I Simply removed the *Geometry Nodes* modifier from the ground without applying it.

With this method, the instances don't even lose their UV mapping.

Then I selected all the grass objects and joined them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd>). And I was able to export the grass along with the ground.[image: Final exported file]